# How does the apache lifecycle looks like?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

As part of my learning process, I thought it would be good if I expand a little more knowledge on what I know about apache. I have several questions, and while I know some of the stuff may require a rather lengthy explanation, I hope you can provide an overview so I know where to go looking. (preferably reference to `mod_wsgi`)I have read some resources after searching on google, and what I know arrive from there, so please bear with me.

1. What does the apache lifecyle looks like before, during, and after it receives a http request? Does it spawns a new child process to do the work, or creates a thread in one of the child process?
2. Does apache by default runs under `www-data`? So if that's the case, if I want a directory under my project folder to be used for logs, I can change just the folder group to www-data and allows write access?
3. What user will the python interpreter run under, after being invoked by apache? And what will processes created by `Popen` or `multiprocessing` from there run under?
4. I ran `ps U www-data`. Why are there so many processes with

> S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read:

http://www.fmc-modeling.org/category/projects/apache/amp/Apache_Modeling_Project.html
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess

The first one will tell you all the gory details of how Apache works internally. The latter relate to mod_wsgi specifically and process/threading model.

Comment: It would be more helpful to have the actual answer here, rather than just a shotgun blast of links.

Comment: SO is not designed for posting up of copious amounts of information. Especially when it would take dozens of pages to explain it all properly.

Answer (score 2):

The Apache mpm prefork module handles one connection in one process. To handle connections fast and not spawn processes on demand, apache maintains a process-pool. This explains why you see so many processes in the process-list. If a connection comes in, it is handed to one of the already existing processes.

Some more information is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/prefork.html

The answer to question 2) is yes, apache always runs as www-data und you can grant access to any directory by changing it's group permissions to www-data.